# simplifying powers in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am endeavoring to streamline the following mathematical expression:

```py
expr = 200 * x**5 * y**6    
sym.simplify(sym.sqrt(200 * x**5 * y**6))
```

However, the simplification process has not yielded the anticipated outcome. In pursuit of a resolution, I extended my investigations to encompass the simplification of `sqrt(y**6)` utilizing both the `simplify` and `powsimp` functions. Regrettably, neither of these approaches yielded the desired results.

Upon reflection, it has become apparent that the reluctance of SymPy to simplify `sqrt(y**6)` may stem from the divergence in outcomes when substituting negative values. I also undertook assessments involving `sqrt(y**8)` using both the `simplify` and `powsimp` functions, which, once again, proved ineffective.

Could you kindly elucidate the methodology to effectively simplify this expression? Additionally, I am intrigued by the factors contributing to SymPy's reluctance to apply simplification. Should you possess any recommendations for supplementary resources to facilitate further exploration, I would be immensely appreciative.

Comment: "However, the simplification process has not yielded the anticipated outcome." - What result do you get? What result do you think you should get instead, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sympy will make a sqrt divide the power by 2 if you tell it to assume the variables are positive, which is the only case where `sqrt(x**6) = x**3`, it is only true when x is positive.

```py
import sympy as sym
x, y = sym.symbols('x y', positive = True)
expr = 200 * x**5 * y**6  
sym.simplify(sym.sqrt(200 * x**5 * y**6))
```

```
10*sqrt(2)*x**(5/2)*y**3
```

Comment: You can use the assumption `nonnegative=True`, too.